# How do I verify my phone number on Amazon Sagemaker Studio Labs if it's shorter than 12 digits?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

As of today Amazon are requiring phone number verification before allowing you to use a GPU for compute. The trouble is, when I enter my number in the international format, I get an error asking me to enter a 12-digit phone number. "Enter an12-digit phone number"

The trouble is, my phone number isn't 12-digits long. Even with the international calling code (+ followed by digits) in front of it, the longest I can make it is 11 digits, and that's with the leading zero that doesn't need to be included when using the international calling code.

Has anyone else hit this issue and if so, how have you formatted your number to satisfy Amazon's buggy data validation?

Formatting my number with and without leading zeros, and also adding zeros at the end of it, even though this is incorrect.